Could not add dll files while creating an exe from python script using pyinstaller
I made a program to connect to IBM DB2 using ibm_db module provided by python. While using import ibm_db, I get this error
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing ibm_db: The specified module could not be found.
However, I could resolve this by using **os.add_dll_directory('..\clidriver\bin') **
But when I try to make an executale of this python script, it does not work and gives error as the dll files could not be added to the exe.
I tried making changes to the spec file by entering the dll path in datas but not sure what all changes I need to make.
Can anyone help me what changes I need to make in spec file so that import ibm_db could work.

You have to add hidden imports section in configuration file of pyinstaller
You can follow this link https://youtu.be/A_EpMKmMMKI?si=AJmChELBmrWxtve6
This tutorial will help you out for the hidden imports

Please summary the video here; it will be quicker than requiring everyone to watch a 5-minutes video.
